# ANT: Use "," in <arg> without expansion to multiple arguments

Tags: ant, build.xml

The following ANT exec tag does not behave as expected.

```
<exec executable="c:\scratch\test.cmd">
    <arg value="A,B,C"/>
</exec>
```

When executed, I would expect this to call text.cmd with 1 argument.  However, the arg is being expanded to three separate arguments.

As per the Manual, value is supposed to pass the contents as a single argument, however, it is passed as three (one for each component of the string separated by a comma).

I tried replacing the command "," with a semicolon (;) but this does not work either.  It appears as if arg's value attribute parses the supplied string as if it were a path, which it is not.

Anyone know how to the "A,B,C" to pass as one argument?

For the sake of completeness, my test.cmd file is this:

```
@echo off
echo Arg1: %1
echo Arg2: %2
echo Arg3: %3
echo Arg4: %4
echo Arg5: %5
echo Arg6: %6
echo Arg7: %7
echo Arg8: %8
echo Arg9: %9
```

and the output of the ant build is:

```
 [exec] Arg1: A
 [exec] Arg2: B
 [exec] Arg3: C
 [exec] Arg4:
 [exec] Arg5:
 [exec] Arg6:
 [exec] Arg7:
 [exec] Arg8:
 [exec] Arg9:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been resolved.  I was so focused on the issue being in ant, that I didn't take the time to test how DOS like command lines interpret the command-line arguments.

from Window command line, I ran test.cmd a,c,b and see that the command argument was split, therefore, the issue is not related to ant.  so now I just need to figure out how to force ANT to quote the arguments.

Comment: For anyone reading this, to wrap arguments in quotes just using the single quote form, so that double-quotes are ignored by xml parser, and passed to the argument string:   value='"some,text here"'

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<exec executable="c:\scratch\test.cmd">
    <arg line="A,B,C"/>
</exec>
```

See ant manual for description of how [arguments](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) work.

Comment: the line= property exhibits the same behavior as the value= property.  I still receive the distinctly separate arguments in my test script.

Comment: I am very familiar with the contents of the apache ant manuals, and have review the arguments information, as well as the exec task's pages many times trying to locate anything that suggests that commas will be interpreted as list delimiters and therefore will split the string into multiple arguments.  But nothing in there about this.